# ListView.builder build only children that are visible

Tags: flutter

I have a ListView.builder that contains different videos. Everything works as expected, video players get initialized and disposed correctly but despite that, there are still performance issues and memory overflows.

Due to the nature of ListViews.builder, which builds the children on demand, not all items are rendered and only get initialized when scrolling to it, however, the ListView renders a few items before they are visible. In my case, it initializes 5-8 Video Players, even though only one or two are visible on the screen.

Is there a way I can decrease the range when an item of a ListView is rendered before it is actually on screen, so it initializes only the currently visible VideoPlayers?

Answer (score 1):

By setting the cacheExtent to zero, only the items that are currently visible on the screen will be initialized and buffered. This can be useful in cases where you have a large number of items in the list and want to optimize performance and memory usage.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  cacheExtent: 0.0,
  itemCount: yourItemCount,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    // Your item builder logic here
  },
)
```

Comment: ListView.builder(
  cacheExtent: 0.0,
  itemCount: yourItemCount,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    // Your item builder logic here
  },
)